# Change layout in button css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to make the layout of the Visible Columns button the same as the buttons above to be standardized. But I'm not able to make these changes in CSS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOD9Z.png)

The code where the Visible Columns button is is this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as utils from '../../utils';
import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';

export default function TblApprovedTimesheetReport(props) {

  const headers = [
    { id: 0, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.period'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.period'] : 'Period', value: 'period' },
    { id: 1, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.user'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.user'] : 'Employee', value: 'employee' },
    { id: 2, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.team'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.team'] : 'Team', value: 'team' },
    { id: 3, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approver'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approver'] : 'Leader', value: 'approver' },
    { id: 4, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hourstempo'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hourstempo'] : 'Jira Hours', value: 'hourstempo' },
    { id: 5, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hoursponto'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.hoursponto'] : 'Check-in Hours', value: 'hoursponto' },
    { id: 6, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.reason'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.reason'] : 'Comment', value: 'reason' },
    { id: 8, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.origin'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.origin'] : 'Origin', value: 'origin' },
    { id: 9, name: props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approvaldatetime'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approvaldatetime'] : 'Approval Date and Time', value: 'approvaldatetime' },
  ]

  const [approvedList, setApprovedList] = useState([]);
  const [selectedColumns, setSelectedColumns] = useState(headers)

  useEffect(() => {
    setApprovedList(props.data.approvedTimesheetsList);
  }, [props])

  function onColumnSelect(selectedList) {
    (selectedList && setSelectedColumns(selectedList));
  }

  function hasToShow(columnIdx) {
    return selectedColumns.some(({ id }) => id === columnIdx);
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <div className="hdrtimesheets-element-button">
            <label htmlFor="visibleColumns">Visible Columns:</label>
            <Multiselect
                options={headers}
                onSelect={onColumnSelect}
                onRemove={onColumnSelect}
                displayValue="name"
                showCheckbox={true}
            />
        </div>
        <table id="tblApprTimesheetsReport" className="pages-tbl">
            <thead>
                <h2>{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approvedts'] ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.approvedts'] : 'Approved Timesheets'}</h2>
                <tr>
                  {
                    headers.map((item) => {     
                      return hasToShow(item.id) && (
                        <th onClick={() => sortTableAp(item.id)}>{item.name}</th>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    (approvedList && approvedList.length > 0 && (
                        approvedList.map((item) => {
                          return (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                { hasToShow(0) && ( <td>{utils.formatPeriodDate(new Date(item.periodStartDateISO + ' 00:00:00'))} - {utils.formatPeriodDate(new Date(item.periodEndDateISO + ' 00:00:00'))}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(1) && ( <td>{item.usuario}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(2) && ( <td>{item.team}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(3) && ( <td>{item.approver}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(4) && ( <td>{Number(item.hoursTempo).toFixed(2)}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(5) && ( <td>{((item.horasPonto == '?') ? item.horasPonto : Number(item.horasPonto).toFixed(2))}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(6) && ( <td>{item.reason}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(7) && ( <td>{item.origin}</td> ) }
                                { hasToShow(8) && ( <td>{item.actionDate}</td> ) }
                            </tr>
                          );
                          })
                      )) || (
                          (!approvedList || approvedList.length === 0) && (
                              <tr>
                                  <td colSpan={`${(selectedColumns && selectedColumns.length) || 0}`}><h1>{props.texts ? props.texts['relatorio.timesheets.page.noshowdata'] : 'No data for this interval'}</h1></td>
                              </tr>
                          ))
                   }
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  );

    function sortTableAp(n) {
        console.log("Ordenando: " +n);
        debugger;
        var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
        table = document.getElementById("tblApprTimesheetsReport");
        switching = true;
        dir = "asc";

        while (switching) {
          switching = false;
          rows = table.rows;

          for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
            shouldSwitch = false;

            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
            if (dir == "asc") {
              if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
            } else if (dir == "desc") {
              if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                shouldSwitch = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          if (shouldSwitch) {
            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
            switchcount ++;
          } else {
            if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
              dir = "desc";
              switching = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

The code for the other buttons is below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from '@atlaskit/button';
//import { DatePicker } from '@atlaskit/datetime-picker';
//import { gridSize } from '@atlaskit/theme/constants';
import DatePicker, { registerLocale, setDefaultLocale } from "react-datepicker";
import ptBR from 'date-fns/locale/pt-BR';

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import './index.css'

registerLocale('ptBR', ptBR);
setDefaultLocale('ptBR');

export default function HdrTimesheetsReport(props) {

    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const [accountsuggestions, setaccountSuggestions] = useState([]);
    const [accounttext, setaccountText] = useState('');

    const [categoryaccountsuggestions, setcategoryaccountSuggestions] = useState([]);
    const [categoryaccounttext, setcategoryaccountText] = useState('');

    // Team
    function onTextChange(e) {
        let suggestions = [];
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (value.length > 0) {
            const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
            suggestions = props.teamList.filter(v => regex.test(v.teamName));
        } else {
            props.onTeamSelected(null);
        }

        setSuggestions(suggestions);
        setText(value);
    }


    function suggestionSelected(value) {
        setText(value.teamName);
        setSuggestions([]);
        props.onTeamSelected(value);
    }

    function renderSuggestions() {

        if (suggestions.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className="typeahead">
                <ul>
                    {suggestions.map(team => <li key={team.teamId} onClick={(e) => suggestionSelected(team)}>{team.teamName}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>

        )
    }
      // Account

    function onAccountTextChange(e) {
        let accountsuggestions = [];
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (value.length > 0) {
          const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
          accountsuggestions = props.accountList.filter(v => regex.test(v.accountName));
        } else {
            props.onAccountSelected(null);
        }
     
        setaccountSuggestions(accountsuggestions);
        setaccountText(value);
    }
      
      
    function suggestionAccountSelected(value) {
          setaccountText(value.accountName);
          setaccountSuggestions([]);
          props.onAccountSelected(value);
    }

    function renderAccountSuggestions() {
        if (accountsuggestions.length === 0) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className="typeahead">
                <ul>
                    {accountsuggestions.map(account => <li key={account.accountId} onClick={(e)=>suggestionAccountSelected(account)}>{account.accountName}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
          
        )
    }

      // Category Account

    function onCategoryAccountTextChange(e) {
        let categoryaccountsuggestions = [];
        const value = e.target.value;
        if (value.length > 0) {
          const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, `i`);
          categoryaccountsuggestions = props.categoryaccountList.filter(v => regex.test(v.categoryaccountName));
        } else {
            props.onCategoryAccountSelected(null);
        }
     
        setcategoryaccountSuggestions(categoryaccountsuggestions);
        setcategoryaccountText(value);
    }
      
      
    function suggestionategoryAccountSelected(value) {
          setcategoryaccountText(value.categoryaccountName);
          setcategoryaccountSuggestions([]);
          props.onCategoryAccountSelected(value);
    }

    function renderCategoryAccountSuggestions() {
        if (categoryaccountsuggestions.length === 0) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className="typeahead">
                <ul>
                    {categoryaccountsuggestions.map(categoryaccount => <li key={categoryaccount.categoryaccountId} onClick={(e)=>suggestionategoryAccountSelected(categoryaccount)}>{categoryaccount.categoryaccountName}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
          
        )
    }

    // Funções de ordenação

    return (
        <div className="hdrtimesheets-container">
            <div className="hdrtimesheets-left-elements">
                <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                    <label htmlFor="stDate">{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.startdate'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.startdate'] : 'Start Date'}:</label>
                    <DatePicker
                        id="stDate"
                        selected={props.startDate}
                        onChange={props.onSetStartDate}
                        selectsStart
                        startDate={props.startDate}
                        endDate={props.endDate}
                        dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
                        showMonthYearPicker />
                </div>
                <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                    <label htmlFor="edDate">{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.enddate'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.enddate'] : 'End Date'}:</label>
                    <DatePicker
                        id="edDate"
                        selected={props.endDate}
                        onChange={props.onSetEndDate}
                        selectsEnd
                        startDate={props.startDate}
                        endDate={props.endDate}
                        dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
                        showMonthYearPicker />
                </div>
                <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                    <Button appearance="primary" onClick={props.handleSearchStart}>{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.search'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.search'] : 'Search'}</Button>
                </div>
                
                {
                    props.selectedTab in [0,1,2,3] && (
                    <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                    {props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.teamsearch'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.teamsearch'] : 'Search team'}: &nbsp;
                        <div className="TypeAheadDropDown">
                            <input onChange={onTextChange}
                                placeholder={props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.searchplaceholder'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.searchplaceholder'] : 'Team'}
                                value={text}
                                type="text" />
                            {renderSuggestions()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                }

                {
                    props.selectedTab in [4] && ( 
                    <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                        {props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.accountsearch'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.accountsearch'] : 'Search Account'}: &nbsp;
                        <div className="TypeAheadDropDown">
                            <input onChange={onAccountTextChange} 
                            placeholder={props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.accountsearchplaceholder'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.accountsearchplaceholder'] : 'Account'} 
                            value={accounttext} 
                            type="text" />
                            {renderAccountSuggestions()}
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    )
                }
                
                {
                    props.selectedTab in [4] && ( 
                    <div className="hdrtimesheets-element">
                    {props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.categoryaccountsearch'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.categoryaccountsearch'] : 'Search Category Account'}: &nbsp;
                        <div className="TypeAheadDropDown">
                            <input onChange={onCategoryAccountTextChange} 
                            placeholder={props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.categoryaccountsearchplaceholder'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.categoryaccountsearchplaceholder'] : 'Category Account'} 
                            value={categoryaccounttext} 
                            type="text" />
                            {renderCategoryAccountSuggestions()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                } 
            </div>
            <div className="hdrtimesheets-right-elements">
                <Button appearance="primary" onClick={props.handleExport}>{props.texts && props.texts['relatorio.page.export'] ? props.texts['relatorio.page.export'] : 'Export'}</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}
```

And the CSS is below

```
label {
    right: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.hdrtimesheets-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 232, 241);
}

.hdrtimesheets-left-elements {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

.hdrtimesheets-right-elements {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element {
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element-button {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element-button .search_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element-button input.searchBox {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73);
    padding: 10px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .18);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
    
.btn-export {
    background-color: white;
    color:  rgba(145, 137, 137, 0.555);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.typeahead {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.TypeAheadDropDown {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: white;
}
    
.TypeAheadDropDown input, .hdrtimesheets-element input {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73);
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .18);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
    
.TypeAheadDropDown ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
    
.TypeAheadDropDown li{
    padding: 10px 5px ;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
}
    
.TypeAheadDropDown li:hover{
    background: lightgray;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Could anyone help me with these changes?

Answer (score 0):

In the css file the class name should be "searchWrapper" instead of "search_wrapper". Here is the updated css:

```
.hdrtimesheets-element-button {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element-button .searchWrapper {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

.hdrtimesheets-element-button input.searchBox {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73);
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .18);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```